# Overwrite cmd Python module complete function

Tags: python

Any ideas on how I can change the 'complete' function from the Python module cmd in order to use my list of commands for auto_complete instead of the do_* ones?

Comment: But the `cmd` module relies on the `do_*` methods to recognize the command names. How are you going to make `cmd` recognize your own command names without the `'do_'` prefix? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What function are you talking about? You mean the (undocumented, but sometimes useful) method `complete` on `Cmd` objects? You can override that the same way as any other method: create a subclass that inherits `Cmd` and defines a different `complete` function with the same parameters. (Or, if you really want to, by monkeypatching the class, but you don't want to.)

Comment: But I don't know what good that would do for you. A `Cmd` isn't going to call anything but the `do_*` functions. And, after a command is entered, it's going to look for `complete_*` functions to complete the arguments, and if your `complete_*` functions don't have matching `do_*` functions nothing is going to work.